# Error while using managed identity for app configuration with Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0

We have a v4 Azure Function App - isolated .Net7.
We are using Azure App configuration to fetch configs and feature flags.

But Intermittently function app is crashing with below error. (Happens like 2-3 times in a minute)

[This is in Function app -> Logstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waE6Y.png)

[image]

[Host.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivf1e.png)

> {
> "version": "2.0",
> "extensions": {
> "queues": {
> "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:00.100",
> "batchSize": 32,
> "maxDequeueCount": 7
> }
> }
> }

[Program.cs configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECyuc.png)

```
        var appConfigName =
           $"https://{(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment")!.ToUpper() != "PROD" ? "shared-test" : "prod")}" +
           $"-appconfiguration.azconfig.io";

    var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientIdUserAssignedManagedIdentity");
    var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId });

    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
        options.Connect(new Uri(appConfigName),
                tokenCredential)
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "interservice")
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "intraservice-functionapp")
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment")}-functionapp")
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment")}-interservice")
               .ConfigureKeyVault(kv => kv.SetCredential(tokenCredential))
               .UseFeatureFlags(featureFlagOptions =>
               {
                   featureFlagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
               })
               .Select(KeyFilter.Any, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment"));
    });
```

I am not able to get around this issue.

Note:
I can use connection string to connect to App config. But another problem is I need to connect app config with keyvault, which needs tokenCredential.

Comment: Hmm, that error is kind of odd. It seems to be trying to call the IP address of the metadata service that is available for Virtual Machines. But in App Service/Functions, this address is not used. Instead the endpoint URL is provided to the app through an environment variable called `IDENTITY_ENDPOINT` and it maps to 127.0.0.1 on some random port. So it would make sense that calling the IP address in the error results in that issue. But why would it try it?